# Is there a way to round up a constant to a power of 2 in NASM?

Tags: assembly, constants, nasm

I am trying to make a constant round up to the nearest power of 2 in NASM, is this possible?

By constant I mean a symbol that you define using EQU.

I don't want to round constant after it is defined, I want to round it while defining it.
The largest power of 2 that I need to be able to round up to is 128.
I can't round the constant in assembly because the value of the constant has to be used when I assemble the program.

Comment: You could do the equivalent of `reg=1; while(reg<val) reg<<=1;` and watch out for overflow. Unsure of the relevance of 'constant' which can't be changed.

Comment: I know a bit-twiddle hack to isolate the rightmost set bit (`val & -val`), but not the leftmost set bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2), this algorithm rounds a 32-bit unsigned integer to the next power of 2. You can extend it to a larger input range by extending the obvious pattern.

```
v--;
v |= v >> 1;
v |= v >> 2;
v |= v >> 4;
v |= v >> 8;
v |= v >> 16;
v++;
```

It's simple to translate the code to an NASM macro.

```
%macro RoundPow2 1
  %assign V %1
  %assign V V - 1
  %assign V V | V >> 1
  %assign V V | V >> 2
  %assign V V | V >> 4
  %assign V V | V >> 8
  %assign V V | V >> 16
  %assign V V + 1
%endmacro
```

```
RoundPow2 4
mov eax, V; 4
RoundPow2 6
mov eax, V; 8
RoundPow2 8
mov eax, V; 8
```

You can, if you want, change the macro to a *functional* version using `%define` by manually expanding all the assignments. You might consider writing a script to generate that.

See @vitsoft's answer for a runtime equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

A constant symbol defined with `EQU` cannot be changed, you need to load its value and round the value up.

```
aSymbol EQU 14    ; Arbitrary pozitive integer constant. 
  MOV EAX,aSymbol
  BSR ECX,EAX     ; Most significant bit number (3 in this example) to ECX.
  BSF EDX,EAX     ; Least signifiicant bit number (1 in this example) to EDX.
  CMP ECX,EDX     ; Is EAX power of two?
  JE Done         ; Do nothing when so.
  INC ECX         ; Increase the M.S. bit number (to 4 in this example).
  MOV EAX,1
  SHL EAX,CL      ; EAX=0x00000010 in this example.
Done:             ; EAX is now the nearest power of two (16 in this example).
```

Comment: I think the OP wants a compile-time constant rounded to a power of 2 using a macro.

Comment: @xiver77 A constant is **defined** when OP writes its value to the `EQU` statement at asm-time, so he|she should round it up in their head. Or define two symbols:  `aSymbol EQU 14`  and `roundedSymbol EQU 16`.

Comment: @vitsoft I can't round it up in my head, the constants value is calculated from the value of some other constants which are used as some simple configuration